# client is waiting forever for remote server to return a webpage

Tags: powershell, tcp, f#, suave

I have an application with a server written in F# and serve web files using suave. I remote login using powershell into another machine in the network to run the application (The application is also in one of the network drives). I do that because that machine have access to third party APIs needed for the server. Now when I do `[IPAddress_Of_Remote_Machine]/[html_file]` or `[name_of_pc]/[html_file]` then chrome is waiting forever and doesn't ever return the webpage. This wasn't happening before and I ran into this problem recently. I opened a different port and used it instead of the default one 80. This made things work but the problem keeps showing up after a couple of days. I don't think it's a firewall issue but I'm clueless to why this is happening.

When running netstat -an, this is what I get (I hid the IP address):

[image]

As you can see all of the connections are either in CLOSE_WAIT or ESTABLISHED but not LISTENING. All of these TCP connections is probably because I have PhantomJS and two other APIs running in the application as well. However the loop back address is also open on the same port 5959:
[image]

I'm not sure what is difference between these two but when using PortQryUI to query the remote server it returns a success!

[image]

I have already made an inbound rule for port 5959 on the server so it should be allowed. The web page is stuck at Waiting for `[name_of_pc]`. Also, sometimes this problem disappears and everything works fine.

What is the potential problem behind this? Why would this happen all of a sudden?

**UPDATE:**

I re-ran the application today and it's working correctly. It could be that something is dynamically set within the firewall? Not really sure what is going on. The machine I'm running the server on has a bunch of applications running on it as well so maybe there is an external process that is affecting it?

I made a hello world app with Suave and deployed it on the network drive to test if it's going to work. I opened inbound rule for port 6001
[image]

Then I ran the app:
[image]

However, it's still not working and this time it says the site cannot be reached when I do: `http://[name_of_pc]:6001`.

[image]

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not the loop back address.  0.0.0.0 means 'any ip address on this system'. Most services listen on 0.0.0.0:port# so that you don't not have to manually choose which IP address you actually want to listen on in the case of having multiple IP addresses assigned either to an adaptor or via multiple adaptors. Because you are getting a portqry response I would host a helloworld site and attempt to download it with `invoke-webrequest` or a browser and post the results.

Comment: @TySavercool Strangely, I re-ran it today and it's retrieving the web page correctly.

Comment: @TySavercool I updated my question. My app works but the helloWorld one doesn't.

Comment: If you start your process in PowerShell and then in a CMD window do a `netstat -atn` do you see port 6001 listening?

Comment: @TySavercool yep I do. Here is the line from the output: `TCP    127.0.0.1:6001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost`

Comment: That's odd, I would have expected to see 0.0.0.0:6001. Can you do a `invoke-webrequest 127.0.0.1:6001` and see if you get your hello world page back?

Comment: @TySavercool Just to clarify something, to check if 6001 is listening, I used powershell to remote into the server machine then did netstat. I didn't use CMD.  

Just tried `invoke-webrequest` and it's returning hello world

Comment: ok so that tells me you have a configuration issue with your web server, You are not listening on an IP address that is remotely accessible. Otherwise, you would see 0.0.0.0:6001, meaning any IP assigned to this machine can receive data destined to the socket behind 6001. Give me a bit.

Comment: Could you post the bindings section of your suave cfg? I'm guessing you know where that is since you are using a non-standard port but if you need don't, search for HttpBinding. I suspect you will find it pointing to 127.0.0.1 which is not good enough for remote access. You could try changing it to 0.0.0.0 or to the server's actual IP address. I would try 0.0.0.0 first for the flexibility it provides.

Comment: @TySavercool You are correct. I changed it to bind to any and it's working. However, my app is binding to any as well and the issue still appears from one time to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to an answer so that it can be closed:

Could you post the bindings section of your suave cfg? I'm guessing you know where that is since you are using a non-standard port but if you need don't, search for HttpBinding. I suspect you will find it pointing to 127.0.0.1 which is not good enough for remote access. You could try changing it to 0.0.0.0 or to the server's actual IP address. I would try 0.0.0.0 first for the flexibility it provides

Comment: To cover your concern in the comment thread above: I think you are seeing it not working because of how and where you are accessing it. If you set the IP binding to 0.0.0.0:6001 it should be accessible internally and external to that system on any IP address that is assigned. If you use a specific IP address then you need to make sure that the system you are launching your request from is hitting that IP address. If you are using the DNS name of that server and it turns out that the DNS record is another IP on that system then it is not going to work.

Comment: This is besides the point. The fact that I set it to 127.0.0.1 in the hello world app have nothing to do with the original problem. The problem still happens even when The ip address is set to 0.0.0.0 and is accessed remotely.

Comment: Also, it works sometimes and it doesn't some other time. The IP Address of the remote machine should be correct since it was working. After I have posted my question, it worked the next day so I don't have the issue now but I'm afraid it will come back just like it did in the past.

Comment: ok. Thank you for clarifying. The condition you are describing requires some change to occur between the server and the requesting machine. The scope of troubleshooting this issue is far to broad for my to be of much assistance. I would set your helloworld program up to run and run a looping request on the client machine. When you see the requests stop responding you could immediately run a trace to see if your network path has been interrupted in any way. If not, maybe an application on the server is trying to take the same port?

Comment: Thank you. How can I run a trace to see if network path was interrupted? Not sure if there is another application trying to get to the same port. It could be the case. The app used to run on localhost/ port 80 but then I changed it to port 5858 and it did work for a bit then stopped so I changed it to port 5959. It's about time I try to fix it the right way. Thanks for all the help. I will accept your answer.

Comment: The way that I would handle something like this depend on how frequently it is happening. If it happens within a few minutes to an hour then I would create a looping `invoke-webrequest 127.0.0.1:6001` to your helloworld program. Then you can use PowerShell to check the contents of the response to ensure it contains 'hello world' or whatever your site is returning. Then I would just wait for it to start failing and then do troubleshooting from that client. I'd start with a tracert and then use portqry. If you cannot connect then I would try locally to see if that has failed as well.